# Firebase functions, getting a authentication token for calling another service

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I am trying to generate an auth token to call a deployed Cloud Run service, below if my code to call out to the metadata server:

```
async function auth(receivingServiceURL:string) {
  const metadataTokenURL = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=';
  const options ={
    headers: {
      'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google',
    },
  }
  const response = await fetch(metadataTokenURL + receivingServiceURL, options);
  return response;
}
```

My error is as follows:

```
>      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/dennisy/dev/view/functions/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1455:11)
>      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:5)
>      at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)
>      at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
>      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
>      at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
>      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
>    message: 'request to http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=https://universal-sentence-encoder-lite-xnqffnl2ba-ew.a.run.app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata',
>    type: 'system',
>    errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
>    code: 'ENOTFOUND'
>  }
```

I am calling this from a firebase function.

EDIT: after some initial help, the issue now is that this works fine when deployed to the cloud, but not locally from the firebase functions emulator.

Trying to access any API / URL on the Google Metadata server returns the same result:

```
 FetchError: request to http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=https://universal-sentence-encoder-lite-xnqffnl2ba-ew.a.run.app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal
```

It seems like the resource is not being found `reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal` but cannot be the case as it works fine when deployed.

I am using my master service account key, which has owner permissions to the whole project.

Comment: The Metadata server is not available outside of Googe Cloud. The URL `metadata.google.internal` is not a public DNS domain name. When working from the emulator you must use a service account.

Comment: Also, limit your question to one problem.

Comment: In Google Cloud there is no "Master Account". Even the role "Owner" does not have all roles and permissions. This is not related to your problem, but an important item in the future as you start using more services. For some roles, you must assign them to your service account or IAM Member ID. As a tip, never assign the role "Owner" to any service account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a malformed URI:

```
http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=AUDIENCE
```

Do not forget to specify a value for `AUDIENCE` which will be the Cloud Run service endpoint.

The Cloud Function also needs a service with permissions to access the Metadata server.

By default Cloud Functions uses the following service account:

```
PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

This service account by default has the `Editor` role. This grants a huge number of permissions. The default service account can also be changed to a different service account. The minimum requirement for accessing the Metadata server is the permission `compute.instances.get`.

Comment: Thank you John! Do you work at Google, if yes the URL is from the docs page - maybe you could update it? https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service

Comment: Also @John Hanley also could you elaborate on what permissions are needed?

Comment: the issue remains with your new URL.

Comment: Which service account are you using and what roles are assigned to the service account? If you are using the URL in my answer you will not get the same error.

Comment: I have tested this locally and deployed. Locally I am using a service account which is the project owner (my own key), and deployed I assume the default service account which has Editor role as you pointed out. If I try and access anything from the metadata server I receive just this error `reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal`

Comment: You cannot assume, look up what service account you are using and the roles assigned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201762/discussion-between-dendog-and-john-hanley).

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a chat forum. Edit your question with more details so that we can help you.